Firebase createUserWithEmailAndPassword only creates anonymous users
I am writing account creation functionality for my website with Firebase's username and password method. The current implementation does not work unless I enable Anonymous User creation mode and then ONLY creates Anon users, which is not what I desire. Why is it that this code does not create authenticated users given this is how Firebase asks the code be implemented?
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

const SignUp = () => {

    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "{apiKey}",
        authDomain: "{domain}",
        projectId: "{projectID}",
        storageBucket: "{bucket}",
        messagingSenderId: "{id}",
        appId: "{id}",
        measurementId: "{id}"
    };
      
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    const userSignUp = ({ email, password }) => {
        const auth = getAuth(app);
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
            const user = userCredential.user;
            console.log(user);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;
            console.log(errorMessage);
        });
    };

    function handleSignUp(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const form = e.target;
        const formData = new FormData(form);
        const formJson = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());
        console.log(formJson.email + " " + formJson.password)
        userSignUp(formJson.email, formJson.password);
    }

    return(
        <>
            <h1>Sign Up</h1>
            <form method="post" onSubmit={handleSignUp}>
                <label>
                    Email: <input type="email" name="email"/>
                </label>
                <label>
                    Password: <input type="password" name="password"/>
                </label>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </>
    );
}

export default SignUp

The result of this is this error:

SignUp.jsx:20 POST https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=AIzaSyA4EnTbw40XnyYjHRHYjvWAxJ42STDF3cA 400 (Bad Request)

And this console message:

Firebase: Error (auth/admin-restricted-operation).


Did you enable email/password sign-in in the Firebase console of your project? Not doing that is the most common cause of this error message.

@FrankvanPuffelen yes! I do have it enabled! Only Email/Password is enabled. Once I enable Anon mode, then the code works by creating only Anon users. When Anon is disabled, the error occurs.

Hmm.... I don't see what could be going wrong here. I hope somebody else spots the problem.

@FrankvanPuffelen Is createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, undefined, undefined) creating a psuedo-anonymous user intended behaviour or a side effect? (interestingly, isAnonymous is false)

Ooof... good catch @samthecodingman. I never realized createUserWithEmailAndPassword would do that.

Looking at the definition of userSignUp, you have defined it to deconstruct an object passed in as the first parameter.
const userSignUp = ({ email, password }) => {
  // ...
}

To make this clearer, this has the same functionality without the shorthand:
const userSignUp = (opts) => {
  let { email, password } = opts;
  // ...
}

Because you call userSignUp with userSignUp(formJson.email, formJson.password), this means you are deconstructing a string value instead of an object as you expect - which means both email and password will be extracted as undefined.
// userSignUp("example@example.com", "someExamplePass") would mean:
let { email, password } = "example@example.com";

// email: undefined (because "".email === undefined)
// password: undefined (because "".password === undefined)

It seems that when you call createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, undefined, undefined) that Firebase creates an anonymous user? Which is weird and also news to me, but I can reproduce it in my sandbox. Interestingly, isAnonymous is not set to true on that user.
You either need to use:
const userSignUp = (email, password) => { ... }

userSignUp(formJson.email, formJson.password);

OR
const userSignUp = ({ email, password }) => { ... }

userSignUp(formJson);


Thank you so much! I had no idea those brackets were causing that side effect. I appreciate you looking into this!
